# Uploading large files to server. FTP or WCF?

Tags: iphone, wcf, ftp

i am working on an iphone project that i need to upload relatively large files (about 4-10mb's).

The problem is i am not sure which way is better?

Available options are:

1- Setting up an FTP server and upload files to the server

2- Writing down a WCF that lets me upload files by streaming to the server.

i am wondering which one is more reliable and which one is faster, less demanding on the client device (iphone/ipad)

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this sample: [SimpleFTPSample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html) on developer.apple.com.

I downloaded it and its very simple and useful.

Answer (score 1):

Definetely FTP, since WCF in "compatibility mode" (i.e. basicHttp / wsHttp) will add a huge amount of overhead since you can't send binary content or use MTOM.

Comment: thank you for the answer, i wish i could accept both replies as answers,